# Accessing event data in JavaScript via a string to dictate which input forms to be captured

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I'm currently creating a feature for an application which allows users to create custom forms. This renders fine, however my issue lies in capturing the information after the form is submitted.

For the sake of this question let's say I have an array of input names (as strings).

```
['firstName', 'lastName', 'emailAddress']
```

Upon submission I need to loop through the array and use the strings to determine the target elements to grab the values from.

```
e.target.'array string'.value;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Is `e.target` the `form` ? Is `firstName` `name` attribute of element ? Can you include `html` at Question ? Are the values not currently accessible at `form` submission ?

Comment: yes, e.target is the form and 'firstName' is the name value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms have an [`elements` collection](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements) which is an [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0) keyed by `name`. So assuming `e.target` is the form (e.g., this is a `submit` event);

```
e.target.elements[someVariable].value;
```

Live example:

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var elements = e.target.elements;
  ['firstName', 'lastName', 'emailAddress'].forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + ": " + elements[name].value);
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" value="The first name">
  <input type="text" name="lastName" value="The last name">
  <input type="email" name="emailAddress" value="email@example.com">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Alternately, the more general solution is `querySelector`:

```
e.target.querySelector('[name="' + someVariable + '"]').value;
```

Live example:

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = e.target;
  ['firstName', 'lastName', 'emailAddress'].forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name + ": " + form.querySelector('[name="' + name + '"]').value);
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" value="The first name">
  <input type="text" name="lastName" value="The last name">
  <input type="email" name="emailAddress" value="email@example.com">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this was exactly what I was looking for.