# forEach method of Node.childNodes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, chromium, nodelist

After providing [an incorrect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105267/js-accessing-event-data-via-a-string-to-dictate-which-input-forms-to-be-captur/36105392#36105392) concerning the `.item()` property of [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) for a question, I inspected `__proto__` of the returned `childNodes` of a `form` element and found a `forEach` method.

The `forEach` method of `Node.childNodes` is not documented in the specification of [`NodeList`](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#nodelist), [in `Methods` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), or [Interface NodeList](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-536297177), and does not appear to be mentioned in *[Iterate a NodeList using forEach method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921282/iterate-a-nodelist-using-foreach-method)* or pages linked to that Question; though it appears available in Chromium 50.

Is the method available only at relatively recent versions of Chrome / Chromium? If yes, is this documented?

Is there any documentation concerning the `forEach()` method of `Node.childNodes`?

---

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = e.target;
  form.childNodes.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.tagName === "INPUT" && el.type !== "submit")
      snippet.log("name:" + el.name + ", value:" + el.value)
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" value="The first name">
  <input type="text" name="lastName" value="The last name">
  <input type="email" name="emailAddress" value="email@example.com">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DOM4 now defines [NodeList](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nodelist) as an iterable:

```
iterable<Node>;
```

According to the [IDL draft](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-iterable), that means

> An [interface](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-interface) can be declared to be ***iterable*** by using an
>   ***iterable declaration*** (matching [`Iterable`](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#prod-Iterable)) in the body of the interface.
>
> ```
> iterable<value-type>;
> iterable<key-type, value-type>;
> ```
>
> Objects implementing an interface that is declared to be iterable
>   support being iterated over to obtain a sequence of values.
>
> > **Note**: In the ECMAScript language binding, an interface that is
> >     iterable will have “entries”, “forEach”, “keys”, “values” and
> >     [@@iterator](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-well-known-symbols) properties on its [interface prototype object](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#dfn-interface-prototype-object).
>
> If a single type parameter is given, then the interface has a ***value
>   iterator*** and provides values of the specified type.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the method available only at relatively recent versions of Chrome / Chromium? If yes, is this documented?

Yes, this is new in DOM4, so not widely available.

> Is there any documentation concerning the forEach() method of Node.childNodes?

See [Add support for [ArrayClass] and use that on NodeList](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229398) on the Chromium bug tracker:

> From https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81573
>
> http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist
>
> DOM4 specs NodeList as having Array.prototype in its prototype chain.
>
> Some more background for this one. [ArrayClass] allows us to do things like document.querySelectorAll('.foo').forEach etc. The patch at bugs.webkit.org has a runtime flag because it is unclear if this will still be possible to achieve.

Historically these array-like objects did not include these methods from the array prototype, leading to code like `Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, function() { ... })`. This is now meant to change in DOM4.