# How to add a class in javascript with selector chaining?

Tags: javascript

I need to add a class to bulk of <a> tag. I have to select the a tag using querySelectorAll method, and all elements are selected. But when I trying to add a class to them it won't added.

I have try the following example.

```
var qc=document.querySelectorAll(".Label ul li a");
qc.className+="newcls";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahhvovvv/

But I can add it through jQuery, but don't use jQuery.
The working jQuery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".Label ul li a").addClass("newcls");
```

});

Comment: `qc` is a collection. You need to iterate over it and add the classname to each collection element. jQuery does that automatically for you.

Comment: Also, qc[i].classList.add("newcls") might work better for you. See: [MDN classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: `[].forEach.call(qc, el => el.classList.add('newCls'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// converts the collection of elements returned from
// document.querySelectorAll() into an Array, using
// Array.from(), then iterates over that Array using
// Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(".Label ul li a") ).forEach(

  // using arrow function syntax to perform the same
  // action on each <a> ('aElement') within the
  // array; here using Element.classList API to
  // add the given class-name:
  aElement => aElement.classList.add('newClass')
);
```

Comment: In DOM4, NodeLists are iterable, so you can use `forEach` directly without `Array.from`. See [forEach method of Node.childNodes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36108712/1529630). But there is not much browser support yet.

Comment: up vote with reference: [MDN Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through the Collection, one way could be:

```
var qc = document.querySelectorAll(".Label ul li a");
[].forEach.call(qc, function(item) {
    item.className+=" newcls";
})
```

[Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/ahhvovvv/3/)

Remember to add a space before the class if you'll use `className`, since you are *editing* the whole `class`, otherwise you could use

```
item.classList.add('newcls');
```

Comment: up vote as I think using [].forEach.call is a safer solution than using Array.from.

Comment: It's an easy solution, however there are some [highlighted problems](https://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/) by Todd Motto, interesting to keep in mind when work in a big codebase. However I think is also a good practice to use `classList` instead of `className`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `qc` is collection. You should iterate through it.
And className is not a collection it is a string where class names separated with space. So here is your code fixed

```
var qc=document.querySelectorAll(".Label ul li a");
for(var i=0; i<qc.length; i++) {
    qc.classList.add("newcls");
    //replace with next line if you need this working in IE before version 10 
    //qc.item(i).className+=" newcls";
}
```

Comment: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630) NodeLists may have enumerable properties like [`item`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-nodelist-item), which you don't want to iterate.

Comment: Yep, it is NodeList, but not in array.
There's nothing criminal in `for .. in`, and by the best is to use `for .. of`