# Best practice to get all specified element to add event listener on them

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm just asking myself what is the best way between these two codes to get all element without getting a JS exception.

#1

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
if (!!items) {
  items.forEach(function(item) { 
    item.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })
  }
}
```

#2

```
var items = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.items'), 0);
if (items.length > 0) {
  items.forEach(function(item) { 
    item.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your anwsers :)

Comment: You don't need `if` condition at all and `querySelectorAll()` returns a node list which as `length` property thus you don't need ` Array.prototype.slice.call` just to use `length` property

Comment: what JS exception do you get?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes`.forEach()` can be chained to `.querySelectorAll()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108712/foreach-method-of-node-childnodes

Comment: Thanks, you are right I didn't need the if condition neither checking length

Comment: If you are not experiencing any exceptions and are asking purely hypothetical the answer could well be down to opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the length of an array if you're looping over it, if there aren't any elements in it, nothing will happen.

Note that `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array-like object, not an actual array, but it does have a length property. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

You could try;

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName( 'yourClass' );

for( var i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ){
  els[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    // your code
  });
}
```

Comment: els is not an actual array

Comment: no, its an array-like object, with a length property, right? that's why I've used a for loop, I was just trying to  point that out because of what the OP tried to do above. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) - Edited my answer to make this clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `"forEach"` is `in` `items`

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
if (items.length && "forEach" in items) {
  items.forEach(function(item) { 
    item.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })
  })
} else {
  if (items.length && !"forEach" in items) {
    items = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.items'), 0);
    items.forEach(function(item) { 
      item.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })
    })
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use spread element to make sure we have an array

```
var items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.items')];
if (items.length) {
  items.forEach(function(item) { 
    item.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })
  })
}
```

or use `for..of` loop

```
for (let item of document.querySelectorAll('.items')) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })
}
```