# how to apply onclick event for all the similar id's using javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have five `div`s and  having ids like this

1) divId_1

2) divId_2

4) divId_3

5) divId_4

6) divId_5

than how I can apply `onclick` event for `div`'s which would work for all the div's using javascript in jquery I am sure how to achieve this but not sure how to do this javascript .

like in jquery we can do as below

```
$('[id^="divId_"]').click(function(){
})
```

same how we can achieve in javascript .

Comment: `$("div").click(function({}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` and `.forEach()`

```js
    document.querySelectorAll("[id^='divId_']")
    .forEach(function(el) {
      el.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.id)
      }
    })
```

```html
<div id="divId_1">click</div>
<div id="divId_2">click</div>
<div id="divId_3">click</div>
```

Comment: its throwing an error 

Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).foreach is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: At which browser are you trying code?

Comment: i am trying this in chrome brwoser .

Comment: The code should return expected result at Chrome. No error is thrown at Chromium 61, see [forEach method of Node.childNodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108712/foreach-method-of-node-childnodes)

Comment: @vikashsrivastava You can alternatively use `.call()` to pass the `NodeList` to `.forEach()`
  `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id^='divId_']"), function(el) {
    el.onclick = function() {
      console.log(this.id)
    }
  })`

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 but still its failing 
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[id^â€Œâ€‹='expandIcon_']' is not a valid selector.
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: above error is for below line of code
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id^‌​='expandIcon_']"), function(el) { el.onclick = function() { console.log(this.id) } })

Comment: How is `XMLHttpRequest()` related to Question? Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('[id^="divId_"]').length; i++){
    document.querySelectorAll('[id^="divId_"]')[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        alert("Hello World!"); 
    });
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector()` returns at most one element

Comment: @guest271314 That is why "querySelectorAll" is first used.

Comment: There is no index property for `.querySelector()`

Comment: Yes, you're right. Updated.

Comment: @Kushtrim it works fine thanks :)

Comment: @vikashsrivastava no problem. It would be great if you could label it as solved.

Comment: @Kushtrim how can i mark it as solved . i am new to this platform .

Comment: @vikashsrivastava https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png