# I want to make an extension that will paste text from a random list. but I can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get the text to paste into any text box or doc,
I have tried a lot of different things but nothing seems to be working.
if there is something I'm missing.
is there a way to do so?
could I get some help?

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Random Word Inserter",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Inserts a randomly chosen word into text boxes when the tab key is pressed.",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "48": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon.png"
      }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Contents.js

```js
const words = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape", "pineapple"];

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "Tab") {
    const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
    inputFields.forEach(function (input) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
      const randomWord = words[randomIndex];
      input.value += randomWord;
    });
  }
});
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Random Word Inserter Settings</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Random Word Inserter Settings</h1>
  <p>No settings available yet.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `inputFields` is a NodeList. If you want to loop it with `forEach` you have to spread it into an array `[...inputFields].forEach()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330086/how-to-loop-through-selected-elements-with-document-queryselectorall

Comment: @GrafiCode `NodeList` has a `forEach()` method. We don't have to spread to an `Array`. I think the issue is content scripts by default are executed in an isolated world. That can be changed in the manifest to `"world": "MAIN"`.

Comment: @guest271314 you're absolutely right, can I ask if `forEach` was added to nodeList in ES6? I clearly remember having to resort to the spread shenanigan in the past

Comment: It's been around for a while https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108712/foreach-method-of-node-childnodes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to update one element, this will work. It can be adapted to update more elements.

```js
const words = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape", "pineapple"];

const inp = document.getElementById("input");
// put the cursor in the input
inp.focus();

const para = document.getElementById("paragraph");

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Tab") {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    const randomWord = words[randomIndex];
    inp.value = randomWord;
    para.textContent += randomWord;
  }
  // disallow the usual processing of the key
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
textarea {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h1>Random Word Inserter Settings</h1>
<input id="input" type="text">
<br>
<!-- 
Use a textarea styled like a paragraph to display the settings 
When the value is updated, the placeholder is hidden
-->
<textarea placeholder="No settings available yet." id="paragraph"></textarea>
```